# Displaying an array returned from a hook

Tags: templating, hook

I'm writing a plugin which has a hook like:

```
craft()->templates->hook('myHook', function(&$context)
{
    return array('hello', 'there');
});
```

While I can call it in a template with:

```
{% hook myHook %}
```

I get an "Array to string conversion", understandably. But I can't work out how to treat the returned data like an array. How can I use `hook 'myHook'` in a `for` loop, or `set` it to a variable? It must be simple, but I've exhausted my random attempts.

Comment: I'm now thinking maybe I should be using a Variable for this instead. I'm not sure what the pros/cons are of either method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Template hooks](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail) are useful if you need to change the current twig context array somewhere inside of a template. If you make any changes to `$context` inside of your hook's function, those changes will be available after your hook tag.

If you just need to return some text or an array, a [variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) will do the trick just fine!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Aaron. Yes, variables seem to do the trick and be a much better solution. It wasn't quite clear from things I've read what the purpose of hooks were, and I went up the wrong path.